# disabling the previous month and next month cell on react fullcalendar

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

i want to disable the previous month and next month dates on react full calendar [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW6BL.png) the click functions should not work on that cells how can i achieve that ?

```
 <FullCalendar
          plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
          // headerToolbar={{
          //   left: 'prev,next today',
          //   center: 'title',
          //   right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
          // }}
          selectLongPressDelay={null}
          initialView="dayGridMonth"
          editable={true}
          selectable={true}
          eventClick={handleEventClick}
          // eventMouseEnter={handleEventMouseEnter}
          dayCellContent={(arg) => {
            const today = new Date();
            const isLastMonth =
              arg.date.getMonth() < today.getMonth() ||
              arg.date.getFullYear() < today.getFullYear();
            if (isLastMonth) {
              return <div className="disabled">{arg.dayNumberText}</div>;
            }
            return arg.dayNumberText;
          }}
          selectMirror={true}
          events={allEvents}
          select={handleDateClick}
          eventContent={renderEventContent}
          eventDidMount={eventDidMount}
          eventWillUnmount={eventWillUnmount}
        />
```

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/showNonCurrentDates might help

Comment: which atribute should be set to false here ?

Comment: Great. You should add your exact solution (including code) below then as an Answer, then the community can benefit (and you can get upvotes!). See also [answer].